# extract a set of a characters between some characters

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a string `email = John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com`

How can I write a java code using regex to bring just the r2d2? 
I used this but got an error on eclipse

```
String email = John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".(.*)\@");
Matcher matcher = patter.matcher      
for (Strimatcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: `Strimatcher.find` sure won't compile since your variable holding a `Matcher` is `matcher`.

Answer (score 1):

To match after the last dot in a potential sequence of multiple dots request that the sequence that you capture does not contain a dot:

```
(?<=[.])([^.]*)(?=@)
```

- `(?<=[.])` means "preceded by a single dot"
- `(?=@)` means "followed by `@` sign"

Note that since dot `.` is a metacharacter, it needs to be escaped either with `\` (doubled for Java string literal) or with square brackets around it.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/gzUNvC/1)

Answer (score 0):

No need to Pattern you just need [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with this regex `.*\.([^\.]+)@.*` which mean get the group `([^\.]+)` (match one or more character except a dot) which is between dot `\.` and `@`

```
email = email.replaceAll(".*\\.([^\\.]+)@.*", "$1");
```

Output

```
r2d2
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSjkjA/1)

---

If you want to go with Pattern then you have to use this regex `\\.([^\\.]+)@` :

```
String email = "John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.([^\\.]+)@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));// Output : r2d2
}
```

---

Another solution you can use split :

```
String[] split = email.replaceAll("@.*", "").split("\\.");
email = split[split.length - 1];// Output : r2d2
```

---

**Note :**

- Strings in java should be between double quotes `"John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com"`
- You don't need to escape `@` in Java, but you have to escape the dot with double slash `\\.`
- There are no syntax for a for loop like you do `for (Strimatcher.find()){`, maybe you mean `while`

Comment: Thanks man. Very helpful. I like the replace all route but what if I don't know what the special character is going to be. Its special character R2D2 special character. How do I get R2D2 , in this case? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Diwas what did you mean, all the 3 solutions return `r2d2` or any character between dot and @ for example if you use another string `firstname.lastname@gmail.come` all the three solutions return `lastname`

Comment: I need to get R2D2 from  string like this:
string email = john.mcgee(special character)r2d2(special character)@hitachi.com
How do I get r2d2, given I don't know what the special character is going to be? Thanks

Comment: @Diwas ok what the expected characters between the two special characters? just letters and numbers?

Comment: yeah just letters and numbers.

Comment: @Diwas I'm not sure, but quick solution `email = email.replaceAll(".*[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]+@.*", "$1");` hope it work with you

Comment: That actually brought in the whole email address.

Comment: @Diwas please to focus on one subject per question, you don't mention that in your question, so it's difficult to understand what you want, I suggest to create a new question where you can share all this information there :)

Comment: will do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your posting the right code. I'll rewrite it based on what it should look like though:

```
    String email = John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".(.*)\@");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
       count++;
       System.out.println(matcher.group(count));
   }
```

but I think you just want something like this:

```
String email = John.Mcgee.r2d2@hitachi.com
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".(.*)\@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
if(matcher.find()){
       System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```